# No navigation bar displayed after log in

Tags: php, authentication, navbar

I have 3 different navigation bars, a different 1 has to be loaded depending on the authority of the user. I have made a function in a different php file so i re use the code in each page. My problem is that after logging in , no navigation bar is being loaded. any suggestions to what might be the problem ?

Code in function.php file

```
function checkAuth()
{
    session_start();


    if(empty($_SESSION['role']))
    {
        require_once('menu.php');
    }

    else if ($_SESSION['role'] == "registered"){
        include('regnav.php');
    }

    else if ($_SESSION['role'] =="admin"){
        include('adminnav.php');
    }




}
```

code in the begging of each page

```
    <?php
 require_once("function.php");
 checkAuth();
 ?>
```

Comment: First, use `isset()` instead of `empty()` to check the existence of $_SESSION['role'].  Second, you havent shown us menu.php, which hopefully sets $_SESSION['role'].  Third, the first time this code runs, it will run menu.php, but won't run again to set any nav bar.

Comment: @SgtAJ I only have the opening of the html and coding of nav bar in the menu.php, since i am calling the session in the function do you think that might be the problem ?

Comment: Well, the first page that has your require_once("function.php") and checkAuth() on it will start your session.  At that point, obviously $_SESSION['role'] will be unset since we just started the session, thus your require_once("menu.php") will be run, but checkAuth doesn't look like it will be run again until we hit another page, so no nav bars will be shown until checkAuth() is run again.

Comment: @SgtAJ I have re written the code and started the session at the begginn of each page instead of in the function. Again no menu is showing :/

Comment: Change your code inside the function to remove the elseif's and replace them with simple ifs.  For example: `if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'registered)`.  That way they will run after menu.php is called and the session variable is set.

Comment: @SgtAJ I have tried this but nothing is appearing. I have inserter a print_r in the beginning of the code to make sure that the session is working and the print_r returns the role value accordingly. the only problem is the menus

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the session result into the function:

## place session call at the top of the rendering page

```
session_start();
$this_session = $_SESSION['role'];

require_once("function.php");
```

## place where you want to render menu

```
checkAuth($this_session);
```

## the function

```
function checkAuth($this_session)
{    
    if($this_session == ''){include('menu.php');}
    elseif($this_session == 'registered'){include('regnav.php');}
    elseif($this_session == 'admin'){include('adminnav.php');}

}
```

Comment: @Chanter test your session to make sure it is set: `if(isset($_SESSION['role'])){echo 'yes isset';} else{echo 'not set';}`

Comment: the session is working as i have made a simple print r to print the value in $_SESSION['role'] and role is being printed, but no menu is shown

Comment: @Chanter i noticed an error in my code... left out `)` in last elseif statement... check that in your code

Comment: That wasnt't the problem :/ thanks for your help though :)!

Comment: @Chanter try passing the session result into the function... i have edited my code to show example

Answer (score 0):

I would personally restructure your pages just a little, like this:

**At the top of each page put:**

```
session_start();
include('function.php');
checkAuth();
```

**Change the function to:**

```
function checkAuth()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['role'])) { require_once('menu.php'); }

    if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'registered') { include('regnav.php'); }
    if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') { include('adminnav.php'); }
}
```

This assumes you aren't using functions in your navbar files, since you don't call any functions to write the navbar.  You could, of course, put both navbars into functions and put both functions into a single `navbar.php` file that you would include at the top of every page (or put the functions into `function.php`), then call the appropriate navbar function from the `checkAuth()` function, like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'registered') { navbar_registered(); }
if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') { navbar_admin(); }
```